# What does "Chances are" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, syntactic-analysis

I often see the expression "chances are" used in English. For example:

> Chances are that the hammer will break.

I think it is probably a contraction, but a contraction from what?

What the chances are, after all? Are the chances "big"? Are the changes "higher than 50%"? Are the chances "almost 100%"?

What, exactly, are the implied *chances* when someone says that?

Comment: It is just a fancy way to say "I guess", which has the same degree of vagueness. It's an opinion, nothing more.

Comment: I use it without the "that". "Chances are the hammer will break." Idk maybe I'm dumb.

Comment: I guess the full formula was something like: The chances are high (that) the hammer will break.

Comment: http://www.oldielyrics.com/lyrics/johnny_mathis/chances_are.html

Comment: Not a contraction but an elision:  "Chances are [good]" meaning "the odds are in favor."  The probability isn't specified but is greater than 50% by definition.

Answer (score 2):

**The expression simply means *it's likely*.**

I couldn't find any reputable evidence that this is a contraction.

And maybe it isn't. One of the meanings of chance is *probability* (see meaning 8 [on this page](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chance), for example.) So *chances are* basically means *it's probable*.

The example given at the above link also shows that the expression can evidently be preceded by a definite article:

> The chances are that the train hasn't left yet.

Although personally I've always heard it without the definite article. And almost always without *that*. So:

> Chances are the train hasn't left yet.